# Error in boot Function output original, bias, std. error

Tags: r, statistics-bootstrap

I attempted to use the **boot** function in R from the **boot** library.  I use the function call

```
bs = boot(mydata, statistic = var, R = 1000)
```

and the output was

```
ORDINARY NONPARAMETRIC BOOTSTRAP


Call:
boot(data = mydata, statistic = var, R = 1000, sim = "ordinary")


Bootstrap Statistics :
    original    bias    std. error
t1* 43.54348 -43.58733    18.93163
```

I understand the results are std. error = sd(bs$t) and the bias is the difference between the original (or observed) variance and the estimated variance bootstrap comes up with.  I'm struggling here because var(mydata) is not equal to the original stated.  Also, is the estimated variance var(bs$t)?

I attempted this other call

```
varF = function(data,i){var(data[i])}
b = boot(mydata, varF, 1000)
```

And the result is

```
Bootstrap Statistics :
original    bias    std. error
t1* 92.45606 -3.767587    39.53009
```

The original agrees with var(mydata) and std. error also agrees with sd(b$t).

In summary, I have three questions:

(1) How is the bias being calculated?
(2) Why do I need to refer to the variance function in this manner?
(3) Am I checking **boot**'s solution correctly?

Thank you in advanced to help me understand better.